# how can I hide effect color in SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter

There is a color-like effect that always appear in my `SliverAppBar`:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I hide effect color in `SliverAppBar`?

```dart
SliverAppBar(
  expandedHeight: 150,
  centerTitle: true,
  forceMaterialTransparency: false,
  // surfaceTintColor: Colors.blue,
  pinned: true,
  forceElevated: false,
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xff2E3358),
  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
    titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
      child: Text(
        'Bengaluru',
        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    background: const Image(
      image: AssetImage('assets/images/bg.png'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SliverAppBar(
...
elevation: 0,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no color effect on your `SliverAppBar`.

You have a background image set for your body widget, and the `SliverAppBar` has the same background image as well. The two images do not come together in harmony, which create an illusion that there is a "color effect" there (in your case, the sky image is darker on the top side and lighter on the bottom side, so when the bottom side meet the other top side, it looks like a shiny color effect).

[image: Illustration]